# How to prevent Next.js page from reloading after sign in with GitHub using next-auth?

Tags: next.js, github-api, next-auth

Using Next.JS with Typescript and next-auth, the page gets reloaded once signed in.

This is the code of the page:

```js
import Link from 'next/link';

import { signIn, signOut } from 'next-auth/react';

const MyPage = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link
            href="/api/auth/signin"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              signIn('github', { redirect: false });
            }}
          >
            Sign In
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link
            href="/api/auth/signout"
            onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              signOut({ redirect: false });
            }}
          >
            Sign Out
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

The code for `auth` API is this:

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth/next';
import GitHubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github';

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GitHubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.MY_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.MY_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
});
```

How could avoid the reload of the page?

I tried with `signIn('credentials',{redirect: false})`, but the problem remained.

I was expecting the page not to be reload once signed in. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with Next, Next Auth and Formik, the following code works for me now after much fiddling:

```js
 const handleSubmit = async (values: { email: any; password: any; }, { setSubmitting }: any) => {
      signIn('credentials', {
        email: values.email,
        password: values.password,
        redirect: false,
      }).then((res) => {
        if (res?.error) {
          console.log(res.error);
        } else {
          setSubmitting(false);
          router.push('/');
        }
      });
    };
```

Comment: works like charm